# Load PrestoDB tables from Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, teradata, presto

I am having issues loading Table/View data from Presto database to Spark.

```
 val prestoDriver = "com.teradata.presto.jdbc42.Driver"

val df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", prestoURL).option("LogLevel",6).option("driver", prestoDriver)
                  .option("user", "xx").option("SSLTrustStorePath", "/xxx.jks")
                  .option("AuthenticationType","LDAP Authentication").option("password", "").option("SSL",1).option("SSLTrustStorePwd", "xxx")
                  .option("dbtable", "<select query with where clause>")
                  .load()
```

In Presto console i am able to see the corresponding queries, but then the queries are timing out after 1 hr with error:

```
com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: Query 20180227_080921_03220_n5vdh has not been accessed since 2018-02-27T08:57:11.162Z: currentTime 2018-02-27T09:02:11.645Z
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryManager.failAbandonedQueries(SqlQueryManager.java:584)
    at com.facebook.presto.execution.SqlQueryManager$1.run(SqlQueryManager.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any my Spark Tasks are running indefinitely without any progress. Looks like the Presto Teradata driver used in Spark is not reaching out to Presto to fetch the results after the query is made.

Can anyone provide some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Is `val df = ...` the whole code and that times out? Don't you execute any actions on `df` afterwards? You should (as no data is fetched with `load` despite its name).

Comment: @jacek , I do have actions like .count & .save on this df. Spark tasks are running in-definitive when an action is performed.

Comment: Show the action (e.g. `count`) and what describe exactly what happens (in the web UI and the logs). That would help understand your case better and possibly come up with an answer. Thanks.